# css styling not being applied

Tags: html, css, stackblitz

I have the most basic static html/css project, and for some reason I can't get my styles to be applied to my html elements in stackblitz. Here's the [project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/htmlpractice22?file=index.html). Could it be that linking the css file with the link tag doesn't work for some reason? Maybe it's not actually in the same directory?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the code you have setup works when it is run locally. The problem may be that StackBlitz does not support the linking of CSS files (has not since at least 2017) have a look at the issue here https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/133

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline styling or in your html file inside  tag you can write the css code

Comment: inside ```<style></style>``` tag

Answer (score 1):

Just put `import './style.css'` in index.js file.